# How to add a label to a border in mui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, border

I would like to have a list wrapped in a border which looks and behaves the same as a textfield border:
[Example textfield and list which should have both same border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8FBH.png)

In the image, the border around the list looks similar than the one around the textfield but most notably, the label is missing. How can I add the label and how would I set up the focus listeners to get the same hover and selection behaviour?

The typescript code for the list:

```
<List dense sx={{ borderRadius: 1, border: 1, borderColor: 'grey.600'}}>
   <ListItem secondaryAction={<IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete"><DeleteIcon /></IconButton>}>
      <ListItemText primary="primary" secondary="group id"/>
   </ListItem>
</List>
```

I am also open for alternative approaches. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to use <TextField />

Comment: I tried that, but how would I then get the list within the textfield?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my answer using React and Mui (only for icon). 
It relies on flex.

We have a main container that only draws its left, bottom and right borders. 
Then we have a header container in charge of drawing the top border in two parts (before and after) and a section with an icon and title.

You can either pass an icon and a title, just a title, just an icon, or nothing at all.

***borderedSection.js:***

```js
import React from "react";
import SvgIcon from "@mui/material/SvgIcon";
import styles from "./borderedSection.module.scss";

function BorderedSection({ icon, title, children }) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
            <div className={styles.header}>
                <div className={styles.headerBorderBefore}></div>
                {(icon || title) && (
                    <div className={styles.headerTitle}>
                        {icon && <SvgIcon component={icon} />}
                        {title && <span className={styles.title}>{title}</span>}
                    </div>
                )}
                <div className={styles.headerBorderAfter}></div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.childrenContainer}>{children}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BorderedSection;
```

***borderedSection.module.scss:***

```css
$border-color: #b2b2b2;

.mainContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 100%;

    border-left: 1px solid $border-color;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color;
    border-right: 1px solid $border-color;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1em;

    .childrenContainer {
        padding: 1em;
    }

    .header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100% !important;

        .headerBorderBefore {
            border-top: 1px solid $border-color;
            width: 1em;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        }

        .headerTitle {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 0.25em;
            width: fit-content;
            height: 2em;
            margin: -1em 0.5em 0em 0.5em;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            font-size: 1em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        .headerBorderAfter {
            border-top: 1px solid $border-color;
            width: 1em;
            flex-grow: 2;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        }
    }
}
```

***usage:***

```js
import React from "react";
import BorderedSection from "./borderedSection";
import InfoIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Info";

function Example() {
    return (
        <div style={{ padding: "2em" }}>
            <BorderedSection icon={InfoIcon} title="Icon and title">
                <div>a first child with quite a long text</div>
                <div>a second child</div>
            </BorderedSection>

            <BorderedSection title="Title only">
                <div>a first child with quite a long text</div>
                <div>a second child</div>
            </BorderedSection>

            <BorderedSection icon={InfoIcon} >
                <div>Icon only</div>
                <div>a second child with quite a long text</div>
            </BorderedSection>

            <BorderedSection >
                <div>No icon and no title</div>
                <div>a second child with quite a long text</div>
            </BorderedSection>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

I hope it helps

Comment: This is a great component, worked well thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing. As I was poking around I noticed that MUI accomplished this by using the fieldset tag. I created a quick and dirty component (OutlinedBox) to get this effect:

```
import React from "react";
import {Box, FormLabel} from "@mui/material";

const OutlinedBox = (props) => {
  const {
    label,
    children
  } = props;
  return (
    <Box>
      <FormLabel
        sx={{
          marginLeft: "0.71em",
          marginTop: "-0.71em",
          paddingLeft: "0.44em",
          paddingRight: '0.44em',
          zIndex: 2,
          backgroundColor: (theme) => theme.palette.background.default,
          position: "absolute",
          fontSize: "0.75em",
          width: 'auto',
        }}>{label}</FormLabel>
      <Box
        sx={{
          position: 'relative',
          borderRadius: theme => theme.shape.borderRadius + 'px',
          fontSize: '0.875rem',
        }}
      >
        <Box
          sx={{
            padding: (theme) => theme.spacing(1),
            display: 'flex',
            gap: (theme) => theme.spacing(1),
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            overflow: 'auto'
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Box>
        <fieldset aria-hidden={"true"} style={{
          textAlign: 'left',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: '-5px',
          left: 0,
          margin: 0,
          padding: '0 8px',
          pointerEvents: 'none',
          borderRadius: 'inherit',
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          borderWidth: '1px',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          minWidth: '0%',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23)',
        }}
        >
          <legend style={{
            float: 'unset',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            display: 'block',
            width: 'auto',
            padding: 0,
            height: '11px',
            fontSize: '0.75em',
            visibility: 'hidden',
            maxWidth: '100%',
            '-webkit-transition': 'max-width 100ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0, 0.2, 1) 50ms',
            transition: 'max-width 100ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0, 0.2, 1) 50ms',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
          }}><span>{label}</span></legend>
        </fieldset>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

export { OutlinedBox };

// Example usage: <OutlinedBox label="Test">Some content here</OutlinedBox>
```

I figured I'd post it here in case anyone needs the same thing and comes across this question. All the styling stuff was copied from the styles MUI was using. There may be a better way to read some of this off of the theme, so if anyone decides to use this you may want to tweak it some.

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to hack a solution which looks the same. I do still hope though that there is a clean way to do this: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98L4O.png).

```
<FormLabel style={{marginLeft: "0.71em", marginTop: "-0.71em", paddingLeft: "0.44em", zIndex: 2, width: "4.2em", backgroundColor: "#383838", position: "absolute", fontSize: "0.75em"}}>Damage</FormLabel>
<List dense sx={{ borderRadius: 1, border: 1, borderColor: 'grey.600', "&:hover": { borderColor: 'grey.200' }}}>
   <ListItem secondaryAction={<IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete"><DeleteIcon /></IconButton>}>
      <ListItemText primary="primary" secondary="group id"/>
   </ListItem>
</List>
```